# GitLab CE: How do I disable security (or auto-login)

Tags: api, security, authentication, gitlab, autologin

I'm looking to setup a demo gitlab running in docker on my local machine and disable the need for a username/password AND also tokens for API requests.

For example, Jenkins has a way to disable security entirely.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see,  all API endpoints require authentication via a token.

There are exception, like seen in [issue 29662](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/29662) "Allow unauthenticated access to the `GET /projects/:id/repository/branches` endpoint": see [merge request 10077](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/merge_requests/10077)

But that illustrates the fact *other* API endpoint would still require a token.

Same for repositories, where only a [Guest permission for public repositories](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/public_access/public_access.html) would avoid the need for username/password.